# how to do regex search in Mongodb using pymongo?

Tags: python, regex, mongodb, pymongo

I want to do a regex mongodb query using pymongo.

```
cond = {'date':'/.*2011-8-11.*/'}
coll.find(cond).count() return 0;
```

but I do this query directly on Mongodb return 25;
Is there any problem in my query?

Comment: Note that this is not really a fuzzy query ... it's an exact matching, instead. A fuzzy search would have been to be able to set up a minimal acceptable proximity (or maximal distance) of any kind, for example as with the ~ operator in solr (term~ or term~0.75 ...). AFAIK it's not possible neither with regex nor mongoDB, unfortunately.

Comment: Is it possible to edit the question with "regex search" instead of "fuzzy search"? That's what the question is actually about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To search with regular expressions from pymongo, you need to use a python regular expression object, not a string with slashes. For your query above, the pymongo syntax would be:

```
import re
# assume connection is set up, and db
# is a pymongo.database.Database instance
date_re = re.compile(r'2011-8-11')
db.collection.find({'date': date_re})
```

Also note that you don't need the `.` character (either in the pymongo syntax or the mongo shell syntax), unless you anchor your regular expression using `^` or `$`.

Comment: Alternatively you can avoid the overhead of creating a regex object by doing `db.collection.find({'date': {'$regex': '2011-8-11'}})`.

Comment: What is the advantage of this answer versus what @TkTech wrote (which worked for me nicely)?